# What is the Play 2.5.x equivalent to acceptWithActor[String, JsValue]?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Before I migrated to Play 2.5.x I used `WebSocket.acceptWithActor` frequently. Now I can't get my web sockets to stay open when using different input and output, in my case, input is String, output is JsValue.

My receiver before Play 2.5.x:

```
object Application extends Controller {
    def myWebSocket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, JsValue] { request =>
        out => MyActor.props(out)
}
```

My receiver in Play 2.5.x:

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer) extends Controller {
  implicit val messageFlowTransformer = 
                  MessageFlowTransformer.jsonMessageFlowTransformer[String, JsValue]
  def myWebSocket = WebSocket.accept[String, JsValue] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => MyActor.props(out))
  }
}
```

In my actor `preStart` is called immediately followed by `postStop`, so this is obviously incorrect, but I can't seem to find any solution in the documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets). 
If I use `WebSocket.accept[String, String]` the socket stays open.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, have you find the solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I went with using `WebSocket.accept[String, String]`

Comment: take a look on my answer, it's dirty but maybe it can work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workarround

My controller:

```
    ActorFlow.actorRef[String, JsValue](out =>
      MyActor.props(
         out,
         ...
      )
    ).map(_.toString)
```

With this you shouln't define a custom messageflowtransformer and at actor level you can still receive strings and return JsValues.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the input message between quotes instead of plain string. In my case (with the same code) worked using the tool [websocket.org/echo](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html)